# Awestruct: Time.now.strftime('%a %-d %B %Y') in asciidoc file

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, awestruct

When I have this code in an `*.adoc` file in awestruct:

```
This website was generated on {localdatetime}.
```

I get:

```
This website was generated on 2015-11-30 11:01:50 CET.
```

But I want it nicely formatted like this:

```
This website was generated on Fri 11 November 2015 11:01:50 CET.
```

I tried these, but they don't work:

```
This website was generated on #{Time.now.strftime('%a %-d %B %Y')}.
This website was generated on #{localdatetime.strftime('%a %-d %B %Y')}.
```

which is strange, because calling Ruby methods with `#{rubyVariable.someMethod()}` in adoc files does work.

Comment: It seems that Asciidoctor can not handle date format:  http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Is-there-a-way-to-set-the-date-format-used-td2735.html

Comment: Pure Assciidoctor can't, but pure Asciidoctor can't do `#{rubyVariable.someMethod()}` either, so I am hoping Awestruct somehow allows it in an adoc file. It works in a haml file.

Comment: What is the type of `localdatetime`? The interpolation is being done with the awestruct page as the context so if it isn't a variable on the page you won't be able to do anything with it. You could try #{localdatetime.class}, that may give you some ideas. What you may be able to do is to add a helper to do the conversion.

Comment: It just prints `{localdatetime.class}`. I don't think it's a ruby value, as it starts with `{`, not `#{`. I think it's an asciidoc value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:page-interpolate: true` on the top of the `*.adoc` file

```
= Website info
:awestruct-description: Website technology and feedback
:page-interpolate: true
```

Then this works:

```
 This website was generated on #{Time.now.strftime('%a %-d %B %Y at %H:%M:%S %Z')}.
```

Output:

```
 This website was generated on Fri 4 December 2015 at 12:31:09 CET.
```

Comment: Ah, I had assumed you already had the page to interpolate true, otherwise none of this would have worked.